# Unable to get property 'addEventListener'

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have been working on a small aspect of my application today and wanted to get a sliding bar on my application. I asked a question this morning where there was some good answers. I have recently wanted to try and answer that i ws given using **Script**, **CSS** and **HTML**.

I am getting to problem to get the **Script** working as it keeps coming up with an error saying:

```
 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference
```

This is the **Script**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var desktops = document.querySelectorAll('.desktop');

    function hide(element) {
        element.style.setProperty('left', '-100%', element.style.getPropertyPriority('left'));
    }

    function hideAll() {
        for (var i = 0; i < desktops.length; i++) {
            hide(desktops[i]);
        }
    }

    function show(element) {
        element.style.setProperty('left', '0', element.style.getPropertyPriority('left'));
    }

    document.getElementById('link-one').addEventListener('click', function () {
        hideAll();
        show(document.getElementById('one'));
    }, false);


    show(document.getElementById('one'));
</script>
```

Here is the **HTML**:

```
<ul>
<li id="link-one">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>One</div>
</li>
</ul>

<div id="one" class="desktop">
  <h1>Sidebar Example</h1>
  <p>This is 1</p>
  <p>Something here.</p>
</div>
```

From what I can work out its not being able to find the ID?

Comment: Can you make a smaller example? Eliminate everything that's not related to the problem. http://sscce.org

Comment: @Kendall Frey Ill take the HTML out, but the Script is the problem.

Comment: The HTML is important. What's not important are the parts of it that are not required to reproduce the problem. We only care about your problem, so please only show us that, and no extra code.

Comment: As you've tagged this with ASP.NET, are you sure you're looking for the correct control ID?  ASP.NET (especially when using MasterPages and/or UserControls) will normally render the control with a name such as `ct100_mainContent_control`.

Comment: See my edit - that's what I think @KendallFrey meant!

Comment: @KendallFrey I have edited the question again

Comment: Your HTML doesn't show us how you are loading the script.

Comment: Hang on, I think we're missing something obvious... is this code in the `<head>` of the page?  If so, it's being run before the elements have been created

Comment: @freefaller Yes, the script is in the 'Head'

Comment: That's the problem, you can't access HTML elements before they've been parsed. Try putting the script at the bottom of your `<body>`, or using `onload` or something like that.

Comment: @KendallFrey Thanks for the answer, I added to the bottom of my code and it worked fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're running the script BEFORE the elements on the page have been created.  That is why the `getElementById` is returning `null`.

There are several ways to get around this...

- (as commented by Kendall) you can move the script to the end of the `<body>`
- You can put your code in a function, and call that function from `<body onload="newFunction();">`
- If you can use jQuery, you can wrap the code in `$(function() { ... });`

Comment: I have added it at the bottom of my body and it works fine. I'm stupid I didn't think of the logic, its just I always add my scripts at the top of my page.

Comment: Glad you've got it to work. If you can use jQuery I would thoroughly recommend it.  It will make your life significantly easier

Comment: Ill have alook around to see how I can make jQuery work aswell but thanks for your answer :)