# HTML5 Audio using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, jsfiddle

I've created my own HTML 'music player', which when the play button is pressed, it calls the Javascript function to play the track. For some reason, I cant get this working in my example, but have been able to do it with others - I cant figure what's wrong with this.

HTML:

```
<div id="audioplayer">
    <button onclick="playTrack()" type="button" id="play-button" class="play" align="left"></button>

    <!--time line - for later use -->
    <div id="audiotimeline">
        <div id="audioplayhead" align="left"></div>
    </div>

    <!--Track -->
    <audio id="MyTack">
        <source src="/music/Bruiser.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
    </audio>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var Track = document.getElementById("MyTrack");

function playTrack() {
    Track.play();
}
```

I can assure you that the /music/Bruiser.mp3 file exists in the stated directory and plays fine in general.

My understanding is that, when the button is clicked, the playTrack() function should be called, which should run Track.play() and play the track, but I cant get it to work. Any ideas why, other than my own ignorance?

I dont think the CSS is relevant so I wont bother posting it here, though I have created a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Klickeroo/v7mh61Lk/1/). This might be somewhat pointless, since I havent linked the audio, however hopeful it gives a better idea of how this hangs together.

NOTE: The JSFiddle makes the play button tiny, however you will see it is there once clicked.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, Apologies, Javascript - thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v7mh61Lk/3/). I did two changes

1. Moved the onClick event to inside the JavaScript file.

`var button = document.getElementById("play-button");`

2. Corrected the Audio ID

`<audio id="MyTack">` to `<audio id="MyTrack">`

Oh... also added audio there to test.

Comment: Thanks, but your updated Fiddle doesnt seem reflect the changes you state you have made, which is a little confusing. Can you please explain more on moving the OnClick event? Can't believe the typo though, shame on me! Thanks again. Oh, also your Fiddle doesnt seem to play audio on Firefox or Edge.

Comment: Your fiddle works nicely, however I'm still struggling to get these changes to work on by website. I'll give it another go tomorrow and update this post with the results. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Inside your function, add `console.log("Inside playTrack()");` So you know if that function got called. Also look at the Console for any error messages that may help.

Comment: Thanks @Loaf, think the problem was my JS script being  called at the top of my HTML, resulting in the following error: Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference. I found [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265385/unable-to-get-property-addeventlistener) link which pointed this out to me, and after moving the script to the bottom of the body this now works as expected. Thanks again.